# Installing a github package without setup.py?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, setup.py

I am trying to install https://github.com/ExaVault/evapi-python.git using pip, but it doesn't have a setup.py so how am I supposed to use it? I want to use the packages it contains, but with no setup.py how am I supposed to use it?

Comment: Why do not you create a setup.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing it looks like a manual job, but you can still use it. Download it as zip here https://github.com/ExaVault/evapi-python/archive/master.zip, extract, go to evapi-python-master folder, go to src, and simply place your code there.

```
import V1Api
import ApiClient

...
```

Comment: Awesome, you are my hero. Can you elaborate? What do you mean by place your code there?

Comment: Create a file in `src` and call it something `mycode.py`, then place above code in it.

Comment: You're welcome. Please make sure to accept this answer by clicking the check mark if it resolved your problem.

Answer (score 5):

Just an unfinished, broken package, it isn't supposed to be installed by Python tools. Install it manually — clone the repo and copy files to `site-packages`.

And send them a bug report. Or better yet a pull-request.

*Upd*. Oh, I see, you've sent [a bug report](https://github.com/ExaVault/evapi-python/issues/4) alredy, nice!

Comment: After reading many posts and getting even more confused, this simple answer did the job. I wish I could give you 100 upvotes instead of 1. Thank you very much.